# Ghost tiles on Mapbox gl raster layer

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I place some rastered papermaps on a google map. http://map.tracks4africa.de/?map=nam
This works fine.

Now I try to do the same on a mapbox gl map. In a first step, it looks OK. but when I zoom in and move the position I get some ghost tiles. It looks like this:

[map with ghosts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2d7A.jpg)

How can I tell mapboxgl to stop drawing the tiles outside the coordinates?

I made a sample page for this on: https://map.tracks4africa.de/sample.html
Open the page and zoom in a bit and move the position.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Tracks4Africa Papierkarten</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
    <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.10.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
    <link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.10.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #map {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
        mapboxgl.accessToken = '<your access token here>';
        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'map',
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
            zoom: 5,
            center: [16, -22]
        });

        map.on('load', function () {

            map.addSource('namibia-nord', {
                'type': 'raster',
                'tiles': ['https://map.tracks4africa.de/namibia/north/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'],
                'tileSize': 256,
                'coordinates': [
                    [-15.13369912, 22.26502144],  // Top, Right 
                    [-23.67632569, 10.82780482],  // Bootom, Left
                ]
            });
            map.addLayer({
                'id': 'Namibia Nord',
                'type': 'raster',
                'source': 'namibia-nord',
                'minzoom': 4,
                'maxzoom': 10
            });

        });

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Thanks for your help

Chrigu

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer by myself. I have to use **bounds** instead of **coordinates**.

```
            map.addSource('namibia-nord', {
                'type': 'raster',
                'tiles': [
                    'https://map.tracks4africa.de/namibia/north/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
                ],
                'tileSize': 256,
                'bounds': [10.82780482, -23.67632569, 22.26502144, -15.13369912]
            });
```